# Spring-boot listener’s @autowire is not work on recent versions

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

Spring-boot listener’s @autowire is not work on recent versions

When using 2.3.1.RELEASE of Spring-boot everything is ok.

```
@WebListener
 public class Listener implements ServletContextListener {
   @Autowired private Environment env;
   @Override public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) { try { if (env == null) // is false
```

When using 2.6.2 of Spring-boot the env will be null

change pom.xml

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>    
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>    
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version><!-- ******** 2.3.1.RELEASE - 2.6.2 ********** -->  
    <relativePath/>
 </parent>
```

sample code is in [this link](https://github.com/maafshar/listenerautowire)

Comment: Listener register is not the problem. using your forwarded link or using @ServletComponentScan("com.example.listenerautowire") annotation can register  Listener. the problem is on @Autowire on Listener on the recent version of Spring-boot.

Comment: An `@Autowired` field cannot be `null` if the object is managed by Spring. If Spring cannot fullfil the `@Autowired` it will crash your application. So if it is `null` it is either not managed by Spring **or** it is accessed very early in the lifecycle. As this is an `@WebListener` I suspect it isn't managed by Spring but rather your servlet container. Try replacing `@WebListener` with `@Component`.

Comment: replacing WebListener with Component solved the problem. tanks @M. Deinum

Answer (score 0):

as an issue I created in the [spring-boot project in GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29305),  this is due to the changes in Spring Boot 2.4 to allow @WebListeners to register servlets and filters. The change in 2.4 requires the Servlet container to be responsible for creating the listener so Spring-based dependency injection is no longer available.

Generally speaking, @ServletComponentScan is intended for registering third-party components where you can't modify the code. If you're in a position to use @Autowired and the like then you should use @Component. An exception to this is where you need to be able to register servlets and filters from your listener. @WebListener should be used in this case.

result of this issue updated the release notes for 2.4.